# Does inference time depend on number of parameter?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, deep-learning, caffe

I have two networks. One has following:

Total params: 2,246,550
Trainable params: 2,246,550
Non-trainable params: 0

and 2nd network has around total Trainable params 333,013

but in case of inference time 2nd network took 0.12 sec
and 1st network taking 0.08 sec on average respectively.

what is reason behind such difference?

Answer (score 2):

You can't necessarily tell that. Suppose with 0.4M parameter network mostly consists of convolutional layer while 2M parameter network consists of fully connected layers. Then 1st one will take longer forward pass. So it will depend on lots of things including depth, parameter, number of operations etc. In general you can say it will depend on number of multiplication.

Comment: The parameter means learnable parameter. For example, resnet and vgg network

Comment: @KimHee I meant learnable parameter too. What is your point?

Comment: Yes, In the figure 3 of the paper arxiv.org/abs/1608.06993 , this scheme shows less parameter. Do you guess which one is faster?

Comment: @KimHee The paper already says DenseNet requires fewer parameters and flops than ResNet for similar performance.

Comment: Yes, that is my point. SO, if we have a network that has fewer parameters and flops, can we conclude that it spend less computational time in inference phase?

Comment: @KimHee As I already pointed out just because this case suggest so it can't be confirmed always. Do you even understand my answer?

Answer (score 2):

Although the number of parameters does affect the test time of a net, it is by far not the only factor. You should also take into account the size of the data/features upon which the learned filters/weights are applied.

For example, consider two simple conv-nets:
 - net `A` has a single 7x7 filter
 - net `B` has a single 3x3 filter

It's clear that net `A` has 49 parameters while net `B` has only 9.
However, the input to net `A` is a 150x150 image while to net `B` the input is 1500x1500 image.
Clearly, under these settings, net `B` will take longer to process the input.

In many occasions, deep nets mix conv layer with fully connected layers, which makes it difficult/impossible to compare the number of flops for the "same sized input".

BTW, it is still an open issue is caffe to add a functionality to [compute the number of FLOPS required for a net](https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/issues/2507).

Comment: Thanks shai, but for fair comparison, we need to consider same input dimension. And parameter in here is learnable parameter only

Comment: You cannot always make a "fair" comparison. For example, ResNets usually has relatively few parameters, but are very deep thus having input/feature size very large. On the other hand, VGG nets has HUGE fully conectted layers with TONS of parameters, but relatively small input/feature size. So you cannot conclude FLOPS from number of parameters alone.

Comment: OK, I have found one paper about that https://arxiv.org/abs/1608.06993 . In the Fig3. this scheme shows less parameter. Do you guess which one is faster?

Answer (score -1):

Of course bigger (more complex network) will take more time to evaluate an input because inference require propagating the input through all the network to get to the last layer (output). So it's normal that It's proportional to the number of parameter, i.e. correlated to depth, number of neurons per layer and type of connexion between each two layers.